# Saving Array to Database in CakePHP

Tags: arrays, cakephp, model, controller

I'm out of ideas here is my controller:

```
class GoogleNewsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'GoogleNews';
    var $uses = array('GoogleNews', 'SavedNews');
    var $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    function index() {

$saved = $this->set('news',$this->GoogleNews->find('all'));
```

Im reading data from 'GoogleNews' and they are in my array. Array looks like this:

```
  array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["GoogleNews"]=>
    array(12) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(32) "FIFA 11 fÃ¼r 25,49â‚¬ aus Jersey"
      ["link"]=>
      string(54) "http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/myDealZ/~3/HuNxRhQJraQ/"
      ["pubDate"]=>
      string(31) "Mon, 06 Dec 2010 10:53:22 +0000"
      ["creator"]=>
      string(5) "admin"
      ["guid"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
    string(30) "http://www.mydealz.de/?p=15137"
    ["isPermaLink"]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
  ["description"]=>
  string(355) "
```

And I want to save elements to my database 'SavedNews'
I need to save description and title.
Can anybody tell me how should I write it?

```
 $this->SavedNews->set(array('description' =>$this->GoogleNews->find('description')));
```

Is this a solution?
Its only way that it works, but it puts null values to my columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, the following should work.

In your controller:

```
class NewsController extends AppController
{
    function import_from_google()
    {
        // Load the GoogleNews model and retrieve a set of its records
        $this->loadModel('GoogleNews');
        $newsFromGoogle = $this->GoogleNews->find('all');

        $this->loadModel('SavedNews');
        foreach ($newsFromGoogle as $_one) {

            // Reset the SavedNews model in preparation for an iterated save
            $this->SavedNews->create();

            // Assemble an array of input data appropriate for Model::save()
            // from the current GoogleNews row
            $saveable = array(
              'SavedNews' => array(
                'title' => $_one['GoogleNews']['title'],
                'description' => $_one['GoogleNews']['description']
              )
            );

            // send the array off to the model to be saved
            $this->SavedNews->save($saveable);
         }

         $this->autoRender = false; // No need to render a view
    }
}
```

Refine as desired/required. For example, the iterated save operations should happen in the SavedNews model, rather than in the controller. The above code also has no fault-tolerance.

HTH.